# UICollectionView spacing between rows becomes huge on certain devices

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view with the minimum spacing set to 10 for cells and lines. The horizontal space between the cells adjusts correctly, but I don't know how to alter the vertical spacing between the rows of cells. On the 6, which it was originally developed on, the space is negligible and works fine. But on every other device, the space quadruples in size for no apparent reason. Is there any way to set the spacing between the rows of cells to be a constant value across all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there isn't a way to set the size of collection view cells using AutoLayout. My guess is that the size of your cells just doesn't look good on other screen sizes, so you most likely will need to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol (which extends the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol) and the `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` method.

Although if that's not the case maybe posting some screenshots would help.

Example method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if(self.view.bounds.width > 400){
        return CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width/3-10, height:self.view.bounds.width/3-10)
    }
    return CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width/2-10, height:self.view.bounds.width/2-10)
}
```

Comment: Hmm. What about setting the height? The width doesn't seem to be the problem. I looked into the code and it turns out that the UIView frame was being hardcoded at a set height, so the collection view was compensating. I'm not sure how to make the CGRect with a responsive height though.

Comment: Would you be able to add some screenshots of what you're seeing on the app and if possible your storyboard settings for the collectionview?